# Are environment variables created in systemd on Linux via "set-environment" in-memory or on disk?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, systemd

If I run the command

```
systemctl set-environment VARIABLE=VALUE
```

Will that be stored only in memory, or is it persisted to disk?

Answer (score 4):

systemctl's `{set,unset,import}-environment` subcommands affect only the runtime configuration (i.e. they persist only until reboot, but will survive `systemctl daemon-reexec` and `systemctl daemon-reload`).

If you, in any case, would like to make the environment configuration permanent, you can use the `DefaultEnvironment=` directive in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` (see [systemd-system.conf(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html)) for system-wide environment variable configuration or `Environment=` ([systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html)) for per-unit configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I *don't* want them to persist, I want them only in memory. Is there any documentation you can find that indicates they're never persisted to disk? (Even if they only last till reboot, it's not a guarantee it's not on disk)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any documentation in this regard. I can only point you to relevant pieces of source code. In this specific case `systemctl` simply calls the `SetEnvironment` D-Bus method, which, on the other end, invokes the `manager_client_environment_modify` [function](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/cdc6c95737d26b1746b446dfe662872d593d23c6/src/core/manager.c#L3912). I admit it's not as clear as having a documentation, but that's how it is.